# Displaying generic data into tab contents

Tags: html, laravel

I am sure this is very simple but i am not able to display data under every item tab. I am having problems with where to place the for loops to get the right structure of the tab contents. How can i do this please?

**HTML**

```
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">        
              <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                   @foreach($items as $item)

              <li><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab" >{!!$item->name!!}</a></li>

              </ul>
               //data for a item tab is displayed here -- content
              <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">

              @foreach($item->stuff as $data)

              <label class="mylabel" >  {{$data->name}} </label>
              @endforeach

              @endforeach

               </div> 

               </div>

              </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to loop over your items twice, once to build the tabs `ul` list and then again to display the content for each tab.

Something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">                
        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            // Links for the tabs
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                @foreach($items as $key => $item)
                    <li><a href="#tab_{{ $key }}" data-toggle="tab" >{!! $item->name !!}</a></li>
                @endforeach 
            </ul>

            // Data for the tabs
            <div class="tab-content">
                @foreach($items as $key => $item)
                    <div class="tab-pane{{ $key == 1 ? ' active' : '' }}" id="tab_{{ $key }}">
                        @foreach($item->stuff as $data)
                            <label class="mylabel">{{ $data->name }}</label>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>    
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```